# Friends attending event using Graph API v2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve all friends who are attending an event using graph API ver 2.1 , the solution I found is to use FQL like below but the query is not working correctly as the friend table does not retrieve all friends, also FQL is not supported in ver 2.1.

Any ideas?

`SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid =1564532200443313 AND rsvp_status = 'attending' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.

If v2.0 and above only retrieves friends using the app then your query to retrieve all friends (so that you can check who is attending an event) will not work

The best you can do is

`EVENT_ID/attending?fields=id, name, picture{url}, rsvp_status`

Which is similar to

`SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid =EVENT_ID)`